# In 2016, what solutions does Microsoft officially offer for making SharePoint Online responsive?

Tags: custom-masterpage, mobile, responsive

I've done some work with editing the master page to make SharePoint responsive, but basically it feels like a hack job.

What tools are out there specifically for Office 365 SharePoint Online? I'm looking for official MS tools, not 3rd party options.

I saw some tools out there like the PnP pack, however, they seem to be just for SharePoint on premises.